# Por que o rodapé não fica escondido e bagunça a página

Tags: html5, css3

Preciso que o rodapé fique escondido e apareça conforme vou rolando a página, porém algo está dando errado não sei porquê.
Nesse [link](https://www.fatemi.com.br/home/parallax-cidades/) está o exemplo de como ele deveria funcionar.

Segue meu código:

```css
 a {
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 ul li {
   list-style-type: none;
 }
 .text-center {
   text-align: center !important;
 }
 .menu {
   text-align: center;
 }
 .menu li {
   display: inline;
 }
 .menu li a {
   margin: 10px;
   color: #fff;
   font-family: Gabriola;
   font-size: 1.5em;
 }
 .menu li a:hover {
   color: #f80;
 }
 .seta-menu {
   margin-top: 3%;
 }
 #texto-header {
   margin-top: 20%;
 }
 header h1 {
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: Gabriola;
   font-size: 5em;
 }
 header strong {
   color: #f80;
 }
 header p {
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: gabriola;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   margin-top: -3%;
 }
 .botao-circulo {
   background: transparent;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
   -o-transform: scale(1.5);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
   transform: scale(1.5);
   border-radius: 50px;
   border: 1px solid #fff;
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 10%;
 }
 .botao-circulo:hover {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
 }
 .botao-circulo img {
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
   -o-transform: scale(0.2);
   -ms-transform: scale(0.2);
   -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
   transform: scale(0.2);
   margin-left: -42px;
   margin-top: -17px;
 }
 #video {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 video {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: -100;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   -webkit-transform: scaley(1.72);
   -o-transform: scaley(1.72);
   -ms-transform: scaley(1.72);
   -moz-transform: scaley(1.72);
   transform: scaley(1.72);
 }
 #bg-video {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: -50;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   opacity: 0.55;
 }
 #main-teste {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   min-height: 80%;
   margin: 0 0 600px;
   background-color: #fff;
 }
 #main-footer {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 70%;
   width: 100%;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-color: aquamarine;
 }
 .content-teste {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="main-teste">
  <div class="content-teste">
    <header>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Sobre</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Games</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Eventos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contato</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Ajuda</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Forum</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <img src="http://tapproom.com/testing/tapp/bg.png" id="bg-video">

      <div id="video">
        <video id="Video1" width="100%" height="100%" loop>
          <source src="video/League-warrios.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>

      <div id="texto-header">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum <strong>Dolor</strong></h1>
        <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at risus neque.
          <br>Cras sit amet ligula ut justo commodo porta id ut enim. Nulla est lectus, mollis sit amet vehicula id, volutpat eget mauris.</p>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div>
      <div>
        <footer id="main-footer">


        </footer>
```

Comment: eu acessei seu código e o rodapé está conforme o modelo. Se o que se refere é à caixa onde apareceria o vídeo, instanciado como video-footer? Se for isso, é bem simples.

Comment: ok ja apaguei amigo

Comment: olhando melhor, tenta separar assim, corpo do site que sobrepoe o rodape, e separado dele o rodape, o rodape fixo embaixo do corpo do site e o corpo do site com padding do tamanho q vc quer que apareça do rodape, deve funcionar

Answer (score 1):

olha só, editei o html, onde voce colocou `<div><div>` antes do footer
 é `</div></div>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1">



            <style>


a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center !important;
}
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline;
}
.menu li a {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  color: #f80;
}
.seta-menu {
  margin-top: 3%;
}
#texto-header {
  margin-top: 20%;
}
header h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Gabriola;
  font-size: 5em;
}
header strong {
  color: #f80;
}
header p {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: gabriola;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-top: -3%;
}
.botao-circulo {
  background: transparent;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -o-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.botao-circulo:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
}
.botao-circulo img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
  -o-transform: scale(0.2);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
  transform: scale(0.2);
  margin-left: -42px;
  margin-top: -17px;
}
#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
video {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scaley(1.72);
  -o-transform: scaley(1.72);
  -ms-transform: scaley(1.72);
  -moz-transform: scaley(1.72);
  transform: scaley(1.72);
}
#bg-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -50;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.55;
}
#main-teste {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
  min-height: 80%;
  margin: 0 0 600px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
#main-footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 70%;
  z-index:1;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
.content-teste {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
}

            </style>

    </head>

    <body>

<div id="main-teste">
  <div class="content-teste">
    <header>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Sobre</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Games</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Eventos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contato</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Ajuda</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Forum</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <img src="http://tapproom.com/testing/tapp/bg.png" id="bg-video">

      <div id="video">
        <video id="Video1" width="100%" height="100%" loop>
          <source src="video/League-warrios.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>

      <div id="texto-header">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum <strong>Dolor</strong></h1>
        <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at risus neque.
          <br>Cras sit amet ligula ut justo commodo porta id ut enim. Nulla est lectus, mollis sit amet vehicula id, volutpat eget mauris.</p>
      </div>
    </header>
    </div>
    </div>

        <footer id="main-footer">


        </footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: amigo enchutei o codigo da uma olhadinha para ver se dar para entender melhor

Answer (score 0):

```css
 a {
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 ul li {
   list-style-type: none;
 }
 .text-center {
   text-align: center !important;
 }
 .menu {
   text-align: center;
 }
 .menu li {
   display: inline;
 }
 .menu li a {
   margin: 10px;
   color: #fff;
   font-family: Gabriola;
   font-size: 1.5em;
 }
 .menu li a:hover {
   color: #f80;
 }
 .seta-menu {
   margin-top: 3%;
 }
 #texto-header {
   margin-top: 20%;
 }
 header h1 {
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: Gabriola;
   font-size: 5em;
 }
 header strong {
   color: #f80;
 }
 header p {
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: gabriola;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   margin-top: -3%;
 }
 .botao-circulo {
   background: transparent;
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
   -o-transform: scale(1.5);
   -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
   transform: scale(1.5);
   border-radius: 50px;
   border: 1px solid #fff;
   position: absolute;
   margin-top: 10%;
 }
 .botao-circulo:hover {
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
 }
 .botao-circulo img {
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
   -o-transform: scale(0.2);
   -ms-transform: scale(0.2);
   -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
   transform: scale(0.2);
   margin-left: -42px;
   margin-top: -17px;
 }
 #video {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
 video {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: -100;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   -webkit-transform: scaley(1.72);
   -o-transform: scaley(1.72);
   -ms-transform: scaley(1.72);
   -moz-transform: scaley(1.72);
   transform: scaley(1.72);
 }
 #bg-video {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: -50;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   opacity: 0.55;
 }
 #main-teste {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   min-height: 80%;
   margin: 0 0 600px;
   background-color: #fff;
 }
 #main-footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   height: 30px;
   width: 100%;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-color: aquamarine;
 }
 .content-teste {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   margin: 0;
 }
```

```html
 <div id="main-teste">
  <div class="content-teste">
    <header>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Sobre</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Games</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Eventos</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contato</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Ajuda</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Forum</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <img src="http://tapproom.com/testing/tapp/bg.png" id="bg-video">

      <div id="video">
        <video id="Video1" width="100%" height="100%" loop>
          <source src="video/League-warrios.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>

      <div id="texto-header">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum <strong>Dolor</strong></h1>
        <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at risus neque.
          <br>Cras sit amet ligula ut justo commodo porta id ut enim. Nulla est lectus, mollis sit amet vehicula id, volutpat eget mauris.</p>
      </div>
    </header>
<div>
<div>
        <footer id="main-footer">


        </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estava Faltando o z-index no css do footer, e as duas primeiras divs não estava fechadas corretamente.

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
ul li {
 list-style-type: none;
}
.text-center {
 text-align: center !important;
}
.menu {
 text-align: center;
}
.menu li {
 display: inline;
}
.menu li a {
 margin: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Gabriola;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
.menu li a:hover {
 color: #f80;
}
.seta-menu {
 margin-top: 3%;
}
#texto-header {
 margin-top: 20%;
}
header h1 {
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Gabriola;
 font-size: 5em;
}
header strong {
 color: #f80;
}
header p {
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: gabriola;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 margin-top: -3%;
}
.botao-circulo {
 background: transparent;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
 -o-transform: scale(1.5);
 -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
 transform: scale(1.5);
 border-radius: 50px;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 10%;
}
.botao-circulo:hover {
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.06);
}
.botao-circulo img {
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.2);
 -o-transform: scale(0.2);
 -ms-transform: scale(0.2);
 -moz-transform: scale(0.2);
 transform: scale(0.2);
 margin-left: -42px;
 margin-top: -17px;
}
#video {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
video {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -100;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 -webkit-transform: scaley(1.72);
 -o-transform: scaley(1.72);
 -ms-transform: scaley(1.72);
 -moz-transform: scaley(1.72);
 transform: scaley(1.72);
}
#bg-video {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -50;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0.55;
}
#main-teste {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 min-height: 80%;
 margin: 0 0 600px;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 2;
}
#main-footer {
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 70%;
 width: 100%;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 background-color: aquamarine;
}
.content-teste {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-teste">
  <div class="content-teste">
    <header>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">Sobre</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">Games</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">Eventos</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">Team</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">Contato</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">Ajuda</a> </li>
        <li><a href="">Forum</a> </li>
      </ul>
      <img src="http://tapproom.com/testing/tapp/bg.png" id="bg-video" alt="">
      <div id="video">
        <video id="Video1" width="100%" height="100%" loop>
          <source src="video/League-warrios.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </div>
      <div id="texto-header">
        <h1>Lorem Ipsum <strong>Dolor</strong></h1>
        <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed at risus neque. <br>
          Cras sit amet ligula ut justo commodo porta id ut enim. Nulla est lectus, mollis sit amet vehicula id, volutpat eget mauris.</p>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
<footer id="main-footer"> </footer>
```